# Why my Alexa ReportStatus directive response not working?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I want to enable alexa voice control for my smart home device. I was able to discover device. Now all devices are showing in alexa app. But when I try to turn on the device from my alexa app it is getting stuck. Loader is moving unlimited period of time. It is actually calling ReportStatus directive.

This is the json that I am getting from alexa app for a light. The light has only turn on and turn off capabilities.

```
   {
"directive": {
    "endpoint": {
        "cookie": {
            "detail1": "For simplicity, this is the only appliance",
            "detail2": "that has some values in the additionalApplianceDetails"
        },
        "endpointId": "endpoint-001",
        "scope": {
            "token": "weza|IwEBIGu_tmpSTQaEPvhm0OYy-4ncjve_Au1788TAWR2DC8b7xJlPDiX3HV3rJUtG0qyauIlman4bX4ZCK0-6NvKWagqXNLSdH3bDBLxD_9VtgCQo6wUlEd4DNmL9Yf5sWuUCkV1ALAxxbhqPs3QlTofubxtpSnF05ZWOSjyNUlM3ShryLh7owTywFa_7oXCCaLdLCTiqOm27aPn-yyJEDNG57Sc9iysrZkJHaxVPbdZdcqRmaw9zFGVWOqsgjqiojkKrfztslVL1Ggo6v7Teg8isrZD8osr5HFkWAmZHi8K7UrHmwQnsD9CosgSxSG0avnUoomdsZx3_LPjLJKf5twJrN1vbLolzOgxUbVuAVPVrs8UN40KFEu6eCv_7rYz9AER_61di-4w1K27kjeJvzPMIKlLXLvv6Z-2GyuQq_8M1fUdM0SgiAkqjf92S9SNxezTUiDYdOjB1JrktbQc0WM6OYYXOMjtXcCPx3bqNwWoPZWBk7qptLTurCHcYnnDl27Q0RcJ3u1vFvMaT8l0x87K6wqW2",
            "type": "BearerToken"
        }
    },
    "header": {
        "correlationToken": "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",
        "messageId": "dd8670d5-3afa-483a-93a3-f0fff0ab6572",
        "name": "ReportState",
        "namespace": "Alexa",
        "payloadVersion": "3"
    },
    "payload": {}
  }
}
```

This is the response I am sending from lambda function. It is written in python 3.6.

```
    {
"event": {
    "context": {
        "properties": [
            {
                "name": "powerState",
                "namespace": "Alexa.PowerController",
                "timeOfSample": "2018-12-17T18:17:35.00Z",
                "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 500,
                "value": "ON"
            }
        ]
    },
    "endpoint": {
        "cookie": {
            "detail1": "For simplicity, this is the only appliance",
            "detail2": "that has some values in the additionalApplianceDetails"
        },
        "endpointId": "endpoint-001",
        "scope": {
            "token": "weza|IwEBIGu_tmpSTQaEPvhm0OYy-4ncjve_Au1788TAWR2DC8b7xJlPDiX3HV3rJUtG0qyauIlman4bX4ZCK0-6NvKWagqXNLSdH3bDBLxD_9VtgCQo6wUlEd4DNmL9Yf5sWuUCkV1ALAxxbhqPs3QlTofubxtpSnF05ZWOSjyNUlM3ShryLh7owTywFa_7oXCCaLdLCTiqOm27aPn-yyJEDNG57Sc9iysrZkJHaxVPbdZdcqRmaw9zFGVWOqsgjqiojkKrfztslVL1Ggo6v7Teg8isrZD8osr5HFkWAmZHi8K7UrHmwQnsD9CosgSxSG0avnUoomdsZx3_LPjLJKf5twJrN1vbLolzOgxUbVuAVPVrs8UN40KFEu6eCv_7rYz9AER_61di-4w1K27kjeJvzPMIKlLXLvv6Z-2GyuQq_8M1fUdM0SgiAkqjf92S9SNxezTUiDYdOjB1JrktbQc0WM6OYYXOMjtXcCPx3bqNwWoPZWBk7qptLTurCHcYnnDl27Q0RcJ3u1vFvMaT8l0x87K6wqW2",
            "type": "BearerToken"
        }
    },
    "header": {
        "correlationToken": "AAAAAAQAeXUb9VLQcUVXClbXZQBvIDAIAAAAAAAAiBMdYahxBjRIHYbFACdRe+68uyc0KiCkClvpOCfh5dZw7NlTHoqnbbjPPydl4Nmkh4KLuFtKboYiwENwsVa9Q2WwAgRlEM+SR9PSNrWqnKvKDtulnkVXuTDkHf8f4LskbFd4VhX6cN518TA0MaZZvSfli9CN7KNY7m07P+eIv71nwxUFP5UN4xe4Jsz1V6nLzUGAG2jJIW4Lg0ARHENqDhbFtra4SV+vPXUN8L4qIwvC5xD6/mjsdN7B1ihGy/8djQA2+cxZ3XOEz2UOATyPEDlpVw5PBasQiJbRiSFSZZqEvQ0NHNfPWAWz5ieQXO1z1NAE5RMgn9d5gcEfDecjScP9DE2Yw43MypX/3VMDJmbjuTlhg9AabxLTQndKV8w9JNM1lLXcdp7i2JShOLO0bDDBPqJH1zsiZGJ93zWn+VDOTzDt+482V/AWgcHOWYnB+UZnL9GZFwEKVWTcQ20u2inFK9J11M5wr3ia57WDP6SQ7zkAmERDGfL0wswN/j0vFpqw+0/G7vjAUs2hGyg9oOy7fN2PFntk6IHV8mh47sC+ENj9dujJ9+ENwfEwEi792m7WlA8PGtvxdEqyVib5hY3qfNirqPMhMmPBf2hZlpbUfpf69q9R8GNFq41EZnTlg/AxSBjjLUJazaKQ8RU1VgipcdK1aGupJf5Oi85uEuYWN96OoEtivhUTZXg==",
        "messageId": "dd8670d5-3afa-483a-93a3-f0fff0ab6572",
        "name": "StateReport",
        "namespace": "Alexa",
        "payloadVersion": "3"
    },
    "payload": {}
} 
}
```

Please help me. I am stuck in this for last 2 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is related to your problem. In your response, the `context` element is inside `event`. But according to the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-interface.html#statereport) and [code sample](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-smarthome/blob/master/sample_messages/StateReport/StateReport.json), `context` and `event` should be at the same level.

```
{
    "context": {
        "properties": [...]
    },
    "event": {
        "header": ...,
        "endpoint": ...,
        "payload": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How I missed that. I don't know . I even checked it with Alexa sample codes. But it was the same. Thanks again. You saved me.